# How to assign a variable in the main form after logging in without using Activated event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, the main form which has a `ListBox` gets populated from the database and a login form. the first time the application run all the controls are disabled and when the user login successfully, the login form is closed and using the Activated event I enable the main form and the `ListBox` get populated, the problem with this approach is that every time the main form is not activated (e.g. minimized) and then activated, the event handler is called and the `ListBox` populated again even if the user has been already selected some items, they are unselected except the first item.

here is the login button event handler in the login form:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (VerifyUserNamePassword(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        Frm_Main.auth = true; //auth field is used to check the authorization 
        Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password.");
}
```

this is the Activated event handler in the main form:

```
private void Frm_Main_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (auth)
    {
        listBoxUsers.DataSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
        listBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "UserName";
        listBoxUsers.ValueMember = "Id";
        logOffToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        loginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        groupBox1.Enabled = auth;
    }
```

I know that this is not the best way to accomplish it, but also I can't find an event that can be called immediately after closing the login form to reset the `auth` field other than the `Activated` event.

**EDIT**

As per Reza Aghaei comment I made it like this:

```
public bool Auth
{
    set
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
            logOffToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            loginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            listBoxUsers.DataSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
            listBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "UserName";
            listBoxUsers.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
    }
}
```

and called the `Auth` property in the login form:

```
Frm_Main main = new Frm_Main();
main.Auth = true;
Close();
```

But it doesn't work, the `groupBox1` still disabled, the debugger passes through the setter but the form doesn't change!
I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: i suppose you open up the login form from within the main form? If so: open it up using ShowDialog and put your enable-code below that call.

Comment: What does `Frm_Main.auth = true;` do?

Comment: @RezaAghaei It is a public static variable in the main form, I set it to `true` in the login form if login success

Comment: @nozzleman yes that is how it works, but is this the only way that handle this? I prefer every form to have its own business

Comment: Well, it doesn't change what you have for the worse. you are just moving code from your event handler to another place withing MainForm, so the logic stays in place so to speak.

Comment: Change the auth to a `Property` and in its `set`, enable controls if `value` is true.

Comment: @RezaAghaei this is event better

Comment: @RezaAghaei I got it, thanks

Comment: Forget about `Activated` event, it's not suitable for this requirement at all. The logic depends on when you made the controls disabled. If when you set the property the controls are disabled, then it's enough to put enabling code in setter.

Comment: @RezaAghaei please see my edit

Comment: @Mohamed There is something which seems to be a mistake: `Frm_Main main = new Frm_Main(); main.Auth = true; Close();` Here you created a new instance of `Frm_Main` without showing it, while there is an open instance of your form. You should use the existing instance and not create another one.